# How to get the user id who is executing the Azure automation runbool

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-automation, azureportal

I wish to get the user id who actually initiated the runbook execution through powershell cmdlets within my runbook script. I tried getting the value through [System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent().Name and $env:username but both of them gave the userId as LsaSetupDomain\Administrator. Is it possible to get this value in an Azure runbook script?
Also, for some reasons I could not also find the 'Startedby' field in the runbook job dashboard in the new Azure portal.

Answer (score 3):

You can get the user who started the Automation job using the `startedBy` field returned in the Get Automation Job [PowerShell cmdlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/resourcemanager/azurerm.automation/v2.3.0/get-azurermautomationjob) and [REST API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt163826.aspx).

This will require passing in the job id, which you can get using:
`$PsPrivateMetadata.JobId.Guid`